# Ошибка при открытии БД после смены версии Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-localdb

Сменил версию студии с 2013 на 2015. Были ранее созданные проекты с базой данных ms sql. На новой версии не открываются. Нашёл что нужно в настройках поменять версию sql сервера. Поменял, была:

> (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

Стала:

> (LocalDB)\v11.0

Снова пробую открыть базу данных, та же самая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ещё дело в веб конфиге. Там тоже старый вариант подключения:

```
<add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\Mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Меняю на:

```
<add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\Mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

У базы данных в сервер эксплорере в конце названия добавляется единица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при попытке открыть вылетает уже новая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы базы данных созданные в 13 версии студии можно было запустить и в 15 тоже?

Comment: а версии субд какие?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890200/184217 - похожая проблема (решена в комментариях).