# c# ms server ошибка подключения

Tags: c#, sql-server

Я тут пытаюсь подключить к свою проекту, выдает ошибка...
У меня VS 2017, MS Server 2017 (17.8.1). Как можно сделать?..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввел в MS Server: SELECT @@VERSION..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Периодически я всегда обновляю VS 2017
Буду благодарен!!

Вот, строка подключения:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="D:\Курсовая работа\БД кинотеатр\CinemaBY\CinemaBY\bin\Debug\data\BYCinema.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Когда я хочу выбрать БД, и проверяю его "Проверить подключение", и как на скрине выдает ошибку... Устанавливал первый раз, сразу устанавливал MS Server 2017

Comment: Покажите строку подключения. Вероятно, используется LocalDB? С VS2017 ставится версия localdb 2016. Очевидно, вы пытаетесь открыть файл БД в этой версии.

Comment: Вот, строка подключения: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="D:\Курсовая работа\БД кинотеатр\CinemaBY\CinemaBY\bin\Debug\data\BYCinema.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30 
Когда я хочу выбрать БД, и проверяю его "Проверить подключение", и как на скрине выдает ошибку... Устанавливал первый раз, сразу устанавливал MS Server 2017

Comment: Как я и предполагал, вы подключаетесь к той версии, что устанавливается по умолчанию. Вместо `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` укажите версию вашего 2017-го сервера. Думаю,  `.\SQLExpress` подойдет. Смотрите [здесь](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: У вас инстанс localdb создан версии 2016 (хотя сам sql server версии 2017). Удалите его и создайте заново, используя утилиту sqllocaldb (там есть команда для проверки текущей версии инстанса, и для вывода доступных версий - вызовите их и сравните результат)

Comment: Благодарю, помогло! Заменил на .\SQLExpress

Вопрос, а таким же строка подключения будет работать на других ПК, запустив проекта?

Comment: В общем случае - нет. На каждом компьютере нужна своя строка подключения. Именно поэтому её обычно выносят в конфиг и меняют при развёртывании приложения на целевой машине.

Comment: Понял, а как можно сделать? Если не трудно, показать пример... Я его подключил с помощью Settings и App.config